# json 1.8.2 gem giving me fatal error stdio.h

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

Trying to install

```
gem install json -v '1.8.2'
```

(..or `bundle install`  with `gem 'json', '1.8.2'` in `Gemfile`)

...on Ubuntu 14.04 VM gives me:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing json:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/bin/ruby extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling generator.c
In file included from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/ruby.h:29:0,
                 from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby.h:33,
                 from ../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:5,
                 from generator.c:1:
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/defines.h:26:19: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
 #include <stdio.h>
                   ^
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sudo apt-get install libc6-dev`

fixed it

Comment: Did not fix it for me on 14.04.1